# 12.04 - cannot access wireless at work but can access it at home

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I'm new to ubuntu, and haven't used UNIX since my college days in the 90s. I just installed 12.04 and, after the update, it attached to my home wireless network just fine.

Unfortunately, at work no such luck.  I tried everything I could think of, and scoured way too many possible answers here and elsewhere.  Still no luck.

When I do a iwconfig at work vs. home and do a diff, here is what I get:

```
$diff iwconfig_office iwconfig_home
5,6c5,6
< eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
<           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
---
> eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Evergreen"  
>           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:1C:10:8E:D5:89   
8c8
<           Power Management:off
---
>           Power Management:on
```

`lspci` at home and office are identical.

At the office I have a Motorola 3347 router; at home a Linksys WRT54GS.

At the office I tried 128 bit WEP as well as personal WPA/WPA2.  Neither would connect.

```
iwlist -scan (note that wyolution2 is the connection I'm trying to use):

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 02:21:1E:4B:29:A1
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-23 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"wyolution2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A77796F6C7574696F6E32
                    IE: Unknown: 010582848B960C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0107
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 48:F8:B3:55:E0:F6
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=19/70  Signal level=-91 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"County 10"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0009436F756E7479203130
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0102
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0102
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601001700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F02C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 03 - Address: 24:DE:C6:AF:8E:C0
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Hotspot_194A"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C486F7473706F745F31393441
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B160C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0102
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ACC111BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D16010019000000FF000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C33CC111BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C34010019000000FF000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
          Cell 04 - Address: 24:DE:C6:AF:8E:C1
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0000
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B160C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0102
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ACC111BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D16010019000000FF000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C33CC111BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C34010019000000FF000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
          Cell 05 - Address: 00:21:1E:4B:29:A0
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"wyolution"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000977796F6C7574696F6E
                    IE: Unknown: 010582848B960C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050C000200000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0107
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
          Cell 06 - Address: FE:F5:28:44:3C:D8
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Julie"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00054A756C6965
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030103
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B14
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010210470010BC329E001DD811B28601FEF528443CD8103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010038
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010210470010BC329E001DD811B28601FEF528443CD8103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEE1117FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1603050000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0500001B127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 07 - Address: 00:0F:B3:8A:29:D7
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LightHawk!"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A4C696768744861776B21
                    IE: Unknown: 010582848B962C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0103
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: 9C:D3:6D:C1:AD:35
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR14"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00094E4554474541523134
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B162430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030108
                    IE: Unknown: 050400020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1608001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A00011010440001021047001012AEBDACF164EA95D226FB0349BBA2C4103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200F0040000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 09 - Address: 00:1C:10:A6:BB:0A
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LNDRWY0304 Do Not Use"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00154C4E445257593033303420446F204E6F7420557365
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010002
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD06001018020304
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 10 - Address: 50:3D:E5:30:63:A1
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"aissd"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00056169737364
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C334C101BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A4C101BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3406080800000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080800000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
          Cell 11 - Address: 00:12:CF:B5:5E:20
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0006000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C183048
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32041224606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 12 - Address: 00:1F:C4:8D:B1:80
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryplo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

tion key:on
                    ESSID:"qwest6528"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0009717765737436353238
                    IE: Unknown: 010582848B960C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050C010200000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0107
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
          Cell 13 - Address: 24:DE:C6:AF:8E:E0
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Hotspot_194A"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2660ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C486F7473706F745F31393441
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B160C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ACC111BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B0019000000FF000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C33CC111BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C340B0019000000FF000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
```

Note:  I have half a dozen devices connected to this wireless access point already, including Android devices, W7 and W8.  In addition, this specific machine had connected to it in the past before being re-purposed as a Ubuntu box.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got a phone or other device to try the WiFi on. The issue might not be with Ubuntu, it could be with the WiFi at work. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Please run `iwlist scan` at your office and add the output to your post using the [edit function](http://askubuntu.com/posts/391864/edit).

Comment: Info and responses were added to the original post above.  Thanks.

Comment: In reading out there it seems like it might be related to TKIP encryption, and ubuntu's lack of support thereof.  Anyone know if that could be the case?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is reading this thread, I wanted to update with a resolution.  I moved my system to 3.10 and wireless WPA/TKIP is working fine.